# Swift SpriteKit SKSpriteNode movement

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, touchesbegan

this is the first time I am working with Swift `SpriteKit` and I am having difficulty understanding how can implement the movement of a `SKSpriteNode` touch other SpriteNodes that are arrows. I have positioned the images where I need to be, but when pressing one of the arrows the image doesn't move. I've looked for solutions and can't seem to find one.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var label : SKLabelNode?
    private var spinnyNode : SKShapeNode?

    let monkey = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "monkey")
    let lArrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "leftArrow")
    let rArrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rightArrow")
    let uArrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "upArrow")
    let dArrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "downArrow")


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        monkey.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 140)
        monkey.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width - 300, y: view.frame.height-160)

        lArrow.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width-350, y: view.frame.height-600)
        lArrow.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 50)

        rArrow.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width-260, y: view.frame.height-600)
        rArrow.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 50)

        uArrow.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width-305, y: view.frame.height-540)
        uArrow.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 80)

        dArrow.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width-305, y: view.frame.height-660)
        dArrow.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 80)

        self.addChild(lArrow)
        self.addChild(rArrow)
        self.addChild(uArrow)
        self.addChild(dArrow)
        self.addChild(monkey)
    }

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in (touches) { //---(1)
        let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)
        if let name = touchedNode.name { //---(2)
            if name == "leftButton" {//---(3)
                //move to left
                let moveAction: SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 15, duration: 1)
                monkey.run(moveAction)
            }
            if name == "rArrow" { //---(4)
                //move to right
                let moveAction: SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 15, y: 0, duration: 1)
                monkey.run(moveAction)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there another function to use to move the `SpriteNode` because it doesn't go through statement(2)

Comment: Show the lines of code where you define those button names (leftButton, aArrow).

Comment: First ensure that you are registering touches, i.e., it gets to the test at (2).  If it's not doing that then you probably don't have `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `true`.  If it is getting touches but it's not getting past (2), then whatever node is being touched probably isn't what you expect and/or doesn't have a name. Try `nodes(at:)` instead of `atPoint(_:)` to get all the nodes that the touch would intersect instead of just one.

Comment: I added the lines of code defining the button names

Comment: @bg2b i added ```isUserInteractionEnabel``` and or ```nodes(at:)``` but it did not seem to work

Comment: I.e., you've made an SKSpriteNode by loading an image file, but that node does not automatically get its `name` property set to the image file's name.  You have to set `name` explicitly. Or, since you have the node references available anyway, you can just check `touchedNode == lArrow` or whatnot instead of worrying about node names.

Comment: Thanks @bg2b got it working! Makes sense now, thanks for the clarification!